# Unable to push Json in KAFKA topic

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I try to push data in JSON format inside a KAFKA topic but without success.

I used the following AVRO SCHEMA :

```
{"schemaType":"AVRO","schema":"{\"title\":\"json pipeline\",\"name\":\"MyClass\",\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"com.acme.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"web\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"web\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"createdDate\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"modifiedDate\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"createdBy\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"modifiedBy\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"enabled\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"savedEvent\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"testId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"testName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"type\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"interval\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"httpInterval\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"url\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"protocol\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"networkMeasurements\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"mtuMeasurements\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"bandwidthMeasurements\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"bgpMeasurements\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"usePublicBgp\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"alertsEnabled\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"liveShare\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"httpTimeLimit\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"httpTargetTime\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"httpVersion\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"pageLoadTimeLimit\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"pageLoadTargetTime\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"followRedirects\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"includeHeaders\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"sslVersionId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"verifyCertificate\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"useNtlm\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"authType\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"contentRegex\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"identifyAgentTrafficWithUserAgent\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"probeMode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"pathTraceMode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"description\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"numPathTraces\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"apiLinks\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"name\":\"apiLinks_record\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"rel\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"href\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}},{\"name\":\"sslVersion\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}},{\"name\":\"pageLoad\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"name\":\"pageLoad_record\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"agentName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"countryId\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"date\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"agentId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"roundId\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"responseTime\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"totalSize\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"numObjects\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"numErrors\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"domLoadTime\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"pageLoadTime\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"permalink\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}}]}},{\"name\":\"pages\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"pages\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"current\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}}]}"
```

This AVRO schema is succeffuly pushed in my SchemaRegistry

Then in my producer I used AvroSerializer

```
import time
import json
import sys
import requests

from confluent_kafka import Producer
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringSerializer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.schema_registry_client import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.json_schema import JSONSerializer
from  confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroSerializer

from utils import set_logger

from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic

TOPIC = os.environ.get("MY_TOPIC_IN")
WEB_PAGE_LOAD_URL = os.environ.get("URL")
ACCOUNT_GROUP_ID_1000EYES = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_ID")
TE_BEARER = os.environ.get("TE_BEARER")
LOGGER = set_logger("producer_logger")

def metrics(test_id):
    res = {}
    #url= WEB_PAGE_LOAD_URL + '{}.json?aid{}'.format(test_id, ACCOUNT_GROUP_ID_1000EYES)
    url= "{}{}.json?aid{}".format(WEB_PAGE_LOAD_URL, test_id, ACCOUNT_GROUP_ID_1000EYES)
    session = requests.session()
    headers = {'Authorization': TE_BEARER}
    rep=session.get(url, headers=headers)
    res = rep.json()
    print(res)
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf={"bootstrap.servers":"json_kafka:29094"}
    admin_client = AdminClient(conf)
    topic_list = [NewTopic("my_topic_in", 1, 1)]
    admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list)

    if sys.argv[1] == "json" :

        schema_registry_url = {"url": "http://json_schema-registry:8083"}
        sr = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_url)
        subjects = sr.get_subjects()
        '''retrieve json shcema in schema registry'''
        for subject in subjects:
            #print(subject)
            schema = sr.get_latest_version(subject)
            print(schema.subject)
            if schema.subject == "{}-value".format(TOPIC) :
                my_schema=schema.schema.schema_str
                json_serializer = JSONSerializer(my_schema,sr,to_dict=None,conf=None)
                '''create json producer'''
                json_producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers':'json_kafka:29094' ,
                                      'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8'),
                                      'value.serializer': AvroSerializer}
                                      
                producer = SerializingProducer(json_producer_conf)

    elif sys.argv[1]=="string":
        string_producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers':'json_kafka:29094',
            'enable.idempotence': 'true'}
        '''create string producer '''
        producer = Producer(string_producer_conf)

    while True:

        response_json=metrics(1136837) #300

        raw_json = json.dumps(response_json,indent=4)

        print(raw_json)

        try:
            #producer.produce(topic=TOPIC, value=raw_json)
            producer.produce(topic=TOPIC, value=raw_json)
            producer.poll(1)

        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error("There is a problem with the topic {}\n".format(TOPIC))
            LOGGER.error("The problem is: {}!".format(e))

        LOGGER.info("Produced into Kafka topic: {}.".format(TOPIC))
        LOGGER.info("Waiting for the next round...")
        time.sleep(300)}
```

And then when I launch my producer I have the following error

> ERROR The problem is: KafkaError{code=_VALUE_SERIALIZATION,val=-161,str="'SerializationContext'
> object has no attribute 'strip'"}!>

remark : when I used "string" as argument with my producer it works well

I tried many things without success and really don't understand the error message, any help will be appreciate thanks.

Comment: 1) What arguments are you passing to the script? 2) Does the example code work? https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py 3) `== "json"` doesn't make sense for `AvroSerializer`; you also created a `JSONSerializer` but you don't use it

Answer (score 0):

> 'SerializationContext' object has no attribute 'strip'"

The problem with your code is that you passed the actual class `AvroSerializer` to `value.serializer` property, not an instance of one.

As shown [in the example code](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py), you need to create an instance with the schema, URL, and a serializer function-handle. You then would return a `dict` from the `AvroSerializer` serializer function-handle, and not produce a string from `json.dumps`... If you wanted to send an actual **JSON** string, then you don't need to use `AvroSerializer`, as that would send binary Avro data

Reducing the code to the important parts...

```
class User:
  def __init__(self, ...):
     pass

def user_to_dict(user, ctx):
    return dict(...)


schema_registry_conf = {'url': 'http://...'}
schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)

avro_serializer = AvroSerializer(schema_str,
                                 schema_registry_client,
                                 user_to_dict)  # object serializer function defined here

producer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': '...',
                 'key.serializer': StringSerializer('utf_8'),
                 'value.serializer': avro_serializer}

producer = SerializingProducer(producer_conf)

...
while True:
    # Serve on_delivery callbacks from previous calls to produce()
    producer.poll(0.0)
    try:
        # ... get fields 
        user = User(...)  # create an object
        producer.produce(topic=topic, key='...', value=user,  # sending the object
                         on_delivery=delivery_report)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot OneCricketeer, your answer help me a lot now I succeed to push my data in kafka topic. But I think thhere is a mistake in the following file used by the avro producer : https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/confluent-kafka-python/_modules/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/avro.html. in line 142, def __init__(self, schema_str, schema_registry_client, from_dict=None): I think it is rather def __init__(self, schema_registry_client, schema_str from_dict=None): (schema_str and schema_registry_client) are not at the right place, am I right ? –

Comment: Then second point, I thought that AVRO must be used to describe JSON file format so if I don't need to use AVRO as you said (to push JSON in kafka), could you tell me how can I describe the JSON format of my JSON file ?

Comment: 1) Parameter order doesn't matter. How the constructor is called matters. You didn't call it correctly. Given that the example files (or at least the unit tests) should be tested regularly in the project in every commit, I don't think it's a problem. 2) There's a Jsonschema serializer in that repo https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/json_producer.py

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, I succeed to push my data in Json format thanks to your advice